# DIV containing iframe disappears below break point of 992 in Oxygen Builder

Tags: theme-development, advanced-custom-fields, page-template

I have a dynamic CSS grid using a repeater in Oxygen Builder that displays a mix of images and videos from an ACF repeater.

I have used the following CSS which works fine up to 992px.

```
 .embed-container {
     position: relative; 
     padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
     height: 0; 
     overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This works great for both Vimeo and YouTube videos.

But then at 991px or below, the video elements in the grid disappear.

The image and video divs have conditions set to display based on media type which is selected in the ACF Repeater.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's going on.

https://early.rubberduckdigital.com/our-work/accedian/

I've tried different div positioning, checked the display conditions and all looks fine until below 991.

Comment: You have something hiding video elements under 991.  The inline code changes the video elements directly.  This could be a TON of issues.  Maybe you have the video block hidden on mobile?  It would be better to ask this in the oxygen forums though.

Comment: Thanks. I've asked on the Oxygen forums too. Nothing yet. I've checked to see if the element is being hidden below 992 and there's nothing set there. I'm baffled.

Comment: @philthebass Seems like you figured it out because I checked the link and everything seems to be working ok. Please go ahead and mark the question resolved if you've figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED.

I changed the grid layout to use 2 columns above 992 and 1 col below and added a max-height of 300px to the image and that fixed it.

Thanks for all the input